# Django 1.6: settings file not found no matter what

Tags: django, python-2.7, module, path, python-import

I searched deep and wide, but no solution has worked so far.
I'm trying this with Django 1.6 in my virtual environment. In my `manage.py` file I have the following line:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproj.settings")
```

With this, when I execute `python ./manage.py runserver` I get the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/int/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/int/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/int/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 263, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/home/int/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/int/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/int/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/int/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproj.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): cannot import name current_app
```

Then I added

`sys.path.insert(0, '/home/int/Documents/myproj/myproj')`, where the modules are

to my `manage.py` file and got the same traceback as above.

If I try relative import, i.e. changing that line in `manage.py` to

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", ".myproj.settings")
```

I get the error

`TypeError: relative imports require the 'package' argument`

The file `settings.py` is definitely in `/home/int/Documents/myproj/myproj` (triple-checked).
So I don't know how to solve this seemingly simple issue. Would appreciate some help with it.

Comment: Do you have something like `import current_app` in your settings file? My first guess is that the settings file itself isn't the problem, but the import(s) inside of it. As the error says: `cannot import name current_app`.

Comment: @wfehr No, there is nothing like that in the `settings.py` file, nor in any other .py file. My guess it that `current_app` refers to some standard name in Django.